# What happens if I lock an object while another thread use that variable?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I am not sure how lock works.
What happens if I have a `List<T> list` and 2 threads ?
What happens if thread1 start running first and enumerate that list

```
foreach(T t in list)
{
  // code
}
```

and in the same time, but after thread1 has started, thread2 will lock the list

```
lock(list)
{ 
  // code
}
```

I use `ThreadPool` do to some processing and I need to know how lock really works and if is thread safe

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(method), obj);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[lock keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(VS.80).aspx) doesn't "lock" or "freeze" target object (in a sense preventing from changes).

> lock ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread attempts to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released.

So in your case it won't prevent other threads from enumerating the list.

Answer (score 6):

In the code as written - the enumerator will keep on going. The point about `lock` is that **all** your code needs to agree. If you had used:

```
lock(list)
{
    foreach(T t in list)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Then when your *other* thread attempts to acquire the lock it will queue behind the first - waiting for the first thread to release the lock (either by exiting the `lock` (`Monitor.Exit`), or calling `Monitor.Wait`).

Comment: What about situation when i have two methods, e.g. AddValue and GetValue? I'm using lock(someObj) {} in both methods. But i heard about situation when one thread calls AddValue at the same time when another thread calls GetValue - collection will be modified and exception will be thrown. Does syncing object guarantee that all methods that use it in their lock() construction will be also blocked? In other words i need to block all write operations while reading...It's not clear for me...

Comment: @Laserson yes using lock from ***all*** callers will stop that being a problem. In most cases the brief period of exclusivity is not an issue, but if you have a lot more read threads than write threads, look at ReaderWriterLockSlim which allows one writer **NAND** multiple readers

Answer (score 2):

Lock isn't magic, and it must be used cooperatively. If I want to ensure that changes to some mutable object don't get accidentally stomped on or corrupted by multiple threads then I need to ensure that I only make changes to the object within a lock block.

The only thing that lock ensures is that any other code that is locking on the same object is not running on other threads at the same time, it's just syntactic sugar for acquiring and releasing a mutex.

```
lock(x) // acquire mutex associated with x, or wait until it becomes available
{
    // do stuff
} // release mutex associated with x
```

Edit: MSDN has very worthwhile [under-the-hood details on lock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179(VS.80,loband).aspx), for those who are curious.

Comment: While it is a *logical* mutex, note that this (`Monitor`) is very different to the OS-provided mutex, exposed as `Mutex` in .NET.

Comment: @Marc, yes, that's true, under the hood lock() uses a Monitor, which uses a (little-m) mutex, but this shouldn't be confused with the (big-m) Mutex class which is usually used for cross-process synchronization.